# How to add filters programmatically into a Datacom - DM4001?

Tags: switch

I need to write a code (it may be in C, C++, Java, whatever) in order to add filters into a Datacom Switch (DM4001 - ETH24GX+2x10GX H Series), but I can't find anything on Google to help me.

The problem is not with the code itself. What I can't find is the syntax of how to add/remove filters. Can someone give a hint?

Manually, do I need to telnet and/or ssh the Switch and run commands to add/remove filters?

Comment: Is that a layer-3 switch? It appears to be a layer-2 switch, which would be a transparent device.

Comment: It's a layer-2 switch.

Comment: @RonMaupin according to [this datasheet](http://www.datacom.ind.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/134.4072.49-DM4000-Datasheet.pdf) it is a chassis switch , Layer 3 capable.  It support, among other things XML Management Interface

Comment: Layer-2 switches are transparent devices that do not look at protocols above layer-2. Some vendors have limited MAC address filtering on layer-2 switches, but for real layer-3 (IP) or above (TCP, UDP, etc.) filtering, you need a layer-3 switch.

Comment: So, if I need to block some IP passing by this switch, I can't. Is that right?